# How can a validate input of type int only... in a very simple but effective way? in c++

Tags: c++

There is an array with 9 spaces(elements), where those 9 numbers will be stored which are entered by user.

How would you make sure that they enter only those 9 numbers and that they are not the same?
Finally `cout`(print) them from less to greater?

Comment: Sounds like homework.  How would _you_ do it?  What have you tried?

Comment: That's your input?  A file? Console?  What have you tried, show us some code at least.

Comment: For the sorting part you could use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Or you could start with `std::set` off the bat. I'm not sure which way ends up being better. The other thing that fits nicely is that it can only contain unique values.

Comment: i dont think what you telling will help at all.. elaborating a little bit more with details will be grateful..

Comment: the way i would do it in a simple way i would create an array of course with 9 elements prompt the user to enter num 1 using a for loop

Comment: then i would use an if statement and use isdigit and boolean logic to make sure that numbers between 9-0 are entered

Comment: but don't know how to tell the user that numbers cann't be the same.. the must be different and of course i want to accomplish this task in a simple way not using facing methods

Comment: and its not homework lol

Comment: What does "facing methods" mean in this context?

Comment: "i will post my coding shortly"... I can't see any code so far. At least you could accept chris' answer, after all the work he needed to go through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that ensures numbers in the range [0,9], and ignores duplicates:

```
#include <algorithm> //if using copy printing
#include <iostream> //for cin and cout
#include <iterator> //if using copy printing
#include <set> //for set

CHOOSE A METHOD BELOW AND ADD THE CORRESPONDING INCLUDE

int main() {
    std::set<int> nums; //here's the array

    std::cout << "Please enter nine different numbers." 
                 "Duplicates will be ignored.\n";

    //ADD THE NEXT PART OF THE METHOD, THE DECLARATION

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter the next number: ";

        //ADD THE FINAL PART, GETTING INPUT AND INSERTING IT INTO THE SET
    } while (nums.size() < 9); //do this until you have 9 numbers

    std::cout << "The numbers you entered, in order, are:\n";

    //C++11 printing
    for (const int i : nums)   
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    //C++03 printing using copy
    std::copy (nums.begin(), nums.end(), 
               std::ostream_iterator<int> (std::cout, " "));

    //C++03 printing using an iterator loop
    for (std::set<int>::const_iterator it = nums.cbegin(); //this was to
                                       it != nums.cend();  //eliminate the
                                       ++it)               //scrollbar
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

**First Method:** (better for a wider range)

```
#include <limits> //for numeric_limits
...
int temp; //this holds the current entry
...
//works better when you get out of the range 0-9
while (!(std::cin >> temp) || temp < 0 || temp > 9) { 
//body executes if input isn't an int between 0 and 9

    //clear bad input flag
    std::cin.clear(); 

    //discard bad input
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    //prompt for new number (could also add that you're ignoring to beginning)
    std::cout << "Invalid number. Please enter a new one: "; 
}

//insert the valid number, duplicates ignored, automatically sorted
nums.insert (temp);
```

**Second Method:** (better for a 0-9 range)

```
#include <cctype> //for isdigit
...
char temp; //holds current entry
...
//suitable for 0-9 range 
do {
    std::cin >> temp; 
    if (!std::isdigit (temp))
        std::cout << "Invalid number. Please enter a new one: ";
while (!std::isdigit (temp));

nums.insert (temp - '0'); //add the integer value of the character processed
```

The key here is `std::set`, which only allows unique entries, and automatically sorts the elements.

Comment: that's too complex looking for something simpler than that

Comment: @user1533578, Well, for example, the input validation can be replaced with something similar, but then entering `abc` will mess it up if using an int. I didn't see that they had to be from 0-9, though, so I'll add in an alternative for that. Other than that, it's a matter of adding in the number and printing them.

Comment: @user1533578 BTW, you did not post any code of your own, and you now complain about this good solution?

Comment: how about using a for loop and just simple if stamenet using isdigit?

Comment: i will post my coding shortly please be alert i really appreciate you help my intention are not to complain but rather be corrected... just

Comment: @user1533578, I tidied up the post and split the bulk of it into two separate ways of doing it. I also added an alternative printing method. Notice that you don't need to worry at all about keeping the elements unique or sorted. The first method is just a more overkilled, in this situation, way of getting input that won't screw up your program.

Comment: @user1533578, Also note that the first method bombs a bit when not used with the console. Instead of using `ignore()`, you could input a temporary string to clear out the bad "word".

Comment: how about using if(!cin) or if(!isdigit) or (cin.fail()) i have notice that those work but let say u type 123osojdj that will allow the user to bypass the test of testing whather he entered a number

Comment: @user1533578, `cin >> something` returns `cin`, so that matches your first one. `isdigit` doesn't hold up too well when you have to get the input as a string, check each character, and convert it to the int you need. In your case, it's only one digit, so it's easy to do all of that with just a `char`. The input you gave would cause an input of `123` and `osojdj` for the first method, which would both be invalid. For the second, it would give you three valid numbers and 6 invalid inputs after, checked character by character.

Comment: @user1533578, As for something like `while (!cin.fail())`, it's basically the same thing as the first, but longer. I don't know if you've heard, but it's also a bad idea to use something like `while (!fileIn.fail())` over `while (fileIn >> data)`. I'm not sure if it follows suit for `cin`.